# openlayers geojson read as wkt

Tags: javascript, openlayers, geojson

Is there a way to read geojson in openlayers and convert to WKT format , my problem is that when i add more than one geojson as vector layer , they don't appear as one layer , 
kindly tell me how to display multiple geojson as part of a single vector layer , my code is

```
for (var i = 0; i < content.GeoJsonFiles.length; i++) {
    //color = content.Settings.BreakStyles[totalcolor].Color;
    //totalcolor++;
    var id = content.GeoJsonFiles[i];
    // alert(content.GeoJsonFiles[i]);
    var geojson_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("GeoJSON", {
        strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
        protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
        url:'i.geojson' ,
        format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON({})
        }), renderers: ["Canvas", "SVG", "VML"]
    });
    map.addLayer(geojson_layer);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `'i.geojson'` will always evaluate to "i.geojson" string, no matter what the value of `i` is. You probably wanted `content.GeoJsonFile[i].content`, assuming `content` actually contains URLs, not raw GeoJSON data
- You're creating a new vector layer and add it to the map in each loop iteration. What you're getting (*"they don't appear as one layer"*) is exactly what you told the code to do.

---

High-level outline of what needs to be done instead (assuming `.content` contains raw GeoJSON, I suspect this is the case):

```
var geoJsonLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("GeoJSON", {
    // layer options
});

for (var i = 0; i < content.GeoJsonFiles.length; i++) {
    var feature = content.GeoJsonFiles[i].content;
    geojsonLayer.addFeatures([feature]);
}

map.addLayer(geoJsonLayer);
```

You'd need to clarify what `content.GeoJsonFiles` actually contains and what WKT has to do with all this for a more precise answer.